# Oracle SELECT FOR UPDATE - Demonstration?

Tags: sql, oracle, transactions, locking

I am quite not understanding the lock functionality with SELECT FOR UPDATE.

Here is what I've tried.

```
CREATE TABLE ACCOUNT_TAB (
  ACC_ID int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  BALANCE int NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO ACCOUNT_TAB
VALUES(1, 100);

SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT_TAB FOR UPDATE; 
SELECT * FROM ACCOUNT_TAB;
```

Both SELECT will retrieve the row, but shouldn't the first query lock the row in the ACCOUNT_TAB table?

I have read something about sessions: queries from the same session don't care about the lock. Can I somehow in a single script file demonstrate the lock function? For example, can I run two different sessions in one script so the second call will retrieve an error saying that the row is locked?

Comment: A lock only prevents updates or deletes, not selects

Comment: Okay but still, is there some way to demonstrate the lock in a single script file? If I select for update and then do two updates, it will of course allow both updates since I requested the select for update. Perhaps possible with 2 transactions running simultaniously?

Comment: other session won't see changers until you make `commit`

Comment: It's not clear to me, what exactly you want to "demonstrate" - but to test/demonstrate locking and concurrency you need at least **two** database sessions (transactions) - you can't do that with a **single** script.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - actually we can demonstrate it. See my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your original experiment failed to demonstrate the locking because in Oracle writes don't block reads. The FOR UPDATE clause allows us to avoid situations in which two sessions attempt to **write** to the same record; any number of sessions can read a record.

> "Okay but still, is there some way to demonstrate the lock in a single script file?"

Yes. Here is a script with  a local procedure which uses the `autonomous_transaction` pragma to simulate a multi-user environment:

```
declare
    procedure p1 (p_id in number) is
        pragma autonomous_transaction;
        cursor c23  is
            select * from t23
            where id = p_id
            for update nowait;
        r23 c23%rowtype;
    begin
        dbms_output.put_line('nested transaction');
        open c23;
        fetch c23 into r23;
        update t23 
        set col2 = col2 * 2;
        close c23;
        commit;
    exception
        when others then
            dbms_output.put_line(sqlerrm);
    end;

begin
    update t23
    set col1 = 2
    where id = 1;

    p1 (1);

    commit;
end;
/
```

The first UPDATE statement issues a lock, which causes the procedural call to fail because it can't get a lock (due to use of NOWAIT clause):

```
  ...
  30  end;
  31  /
nested transaction
ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: I have a questions for you, and I would appreciate your answers. Original question was about `SELECT FOR UPDATE` which involves explicit locking. So let's say we do `SELECT FOR UPDATE` instead of `update t23`, how would you start another autonomous transaction (calling `p1` without releasing the locks in the first place. And second question: if you manage to start another AT before releasing lock on `t23`, would not it lead to the deadlock, because main transaction stills holds exclusive lock?

Answer (score 2):

RDBMS will obtain exclusive row-level locks on all rows identified by SELECT FOR UPDATE statement, so only you are the only one allowed to update them. It means that other RDBMS client won't be able to alter any of this records until you perform either a COMMIT or a ROLLBACK. So if you want to test how exactly it works, create two separate client connections and try first to lock record in one session, and then try to update same record in another one.

Comment: flawless answer!