# Oracle can return time out when another connection already use the same table?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11gr2

if i need run an DML (insert, update, delete) in one table of database, firstly he verify if has an active DML using that table. In this momment, if has another operation, my connection wait he has finished.
There's a way to get an "time out" in this cases? Not in a global mode, only for specific cases.

--Edit for more specifications of the problem

Not sure if any kind of lock is actually used. But in my case, there is an old application in Oracle Forms and a new application written by me.

The problem is that when the user opens a specific record to update any field in the old application, and i try to edit the same record in my app, the line is blocked.
So my app it's waiting for the unlock. But the problem is that the user thinks the application is frozen and kill him, losing the changes. 
But this is not the case if another Oracle Forms application attempts to edit. When it does, Oracle Forms displays the message "Could not reserve record (2). Keep trying?". Maybe it's because this old app uses any kind of lock. But i need validate this in the code.

Obs: The number 2 is the number of tries to update.

Comment: I think you might be looking for `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`. See this question for details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44865703/oracle-select-for-update-demonstration

Comment: Hi, yes.. maybe this can resolve only half of my problem. I explain better in the question. Only i need is that oracle return to my app.

Comment: Forms does a select for update when it displays the row. You should do the same in your application, catch the error, and tell the user.

Comment: Yes.. maybe he make this internally, witout code. In this conflict with app's, the best is wait the deactivate of old app (1 week). After, the new app don't have this problem. Thank's all for answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you do a 'lock table .... wait', then it will wait until any DML on this table that is inflight commits, then gives you the lock. This will make any one coming after you wait till you release the lock. Look at the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LOCK-TABLE.html#GUID-4C00C6D9-C5C5-46CC-AD33-A64001744A4C) to see how to use this.
Then there's the possibility of locking a single row (select for update). which is more granular. 
That being said, can you please explain what are you exactly trying to do? As you may not need to do this at all.

Comment: Hi. I edited the post and explaining more about my problem. Basicly, in app A have a response about lock and in app B no. I need to get the same of A in B.